# I am writing unit tests. How To Fix LNK1120 Error

Tags: c++, catch2

I want to write the simplest unit test on visual studio 2017.
But there is an error - "fatal error LNK1120: unresolved external elements: 23"

```
#define  CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"

TEST_CASE("Test", "[test]") {

    REQUIRE(1 == 1);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Usually LNK1120 is not alone but comes with LN2019 (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1120?view=vs-2017) You should respect these messages.